# Spark + Velocity: Unable to load resources (ResourceNotFoundException)

Tags: java, velocity, spark-java, apache-velocity

I'm currently using Spark and trying to use templates via Velocity based on the [documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#views-and-templates).

I'm however having some errors, could anyone provide guidance on how I can successfully load the templates?

```
Aug 22, 2017 2:26:43 PM org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.JdkLogChute log
SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'www/templates/template.html' in any resource loader.
[qtp1951434327-14] ERROR spark.http.matching.GeneralError - 
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'www/templates/template.html'
```

```java
public class Minimal {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("test", (req, res) -> {
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            return render(model, "www/templates/template.html");
        });
    }
        
    public static String render(Map<String, Object> model, String path) {
        return new VelocityTemplateEngine().render(new ModelAndView(model, path));
    }
}
```

I've read and tried solutions on many Stack Overflow questions, however none of them seem to be helping in my case.

Some solutions have included setting properties, or having a particular project structure etc. Though it appears none of these have solved the issue, and leads to the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put template inside resources folder. See [example](https://github.com/perwendel/spark-template-engines/blob/master/spark-template-velocity/src/test/java/spark/template/velocity/example/VelocityExample.java) in spark, you can see maven's [pom](https://github.com/perwendel/spark-template-engines/blob/master/spark-template-velocity/pom.xml) resources definitions.